# Configure MongoDB Replication at AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, replication

I am trying to configure a MongoDB replication at AWS with 3 instances.
I have two instances right now and I can ping each other.
Mongo deamon is running correctly with a same replication name.

But after initiating the primary node, I cannot add the second instance withe a error

```
yaodao:PRIMARY> rs.add("yaodao2:27017")
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: yaodao1:27017; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: yaodao2:27017 failed with Connection refused",
"code" : 74
}
```

Someone sais the "coeection refused" is because no mongod deamon is running at second instance, but I verify that and everything is OK.

/etc/hosts for primary instance

```
127.0.0.1 yaodao1
54.173.155.9 yaodao2
```

/etc/hosts for second instance

```
127.0.0.1 yaodao2
54.175.238.78 yaodao1
```

rs.status() for primary

```
yaodao:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
"set" : "yaodao",
"date" : ISODate("2016-09-17T13:34:01.032Z"),
"myState" : 1,
"term" : NumberLong(4),
"heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "yaodao1:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 1,
        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
        "uptime" : 1132,
        "optime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1474118471, 2),
            "t" : NumberLong(4)
        },
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-09-17T13:21:11Z"),
        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1474118471, 1),
        "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-09-17T13:21:11Z"),
        "configVersion" : 59679,
        "self" : true
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to check connectivity b/w all mongo with one another, using mongo shell? mongo --host --port

Comment: @Astro I tried and it cannot connect to another mongod deamon. So what is the problem?

Comment: @Astro I managed to achieve the goal by setting /etc/mongo.cfg bind_ip = 0.0.0.0, but I dont really understand why. continue to looking for reason.

Comment: By default mongodb  binds to only a local interface.

Answer (score 0):

Please take private IP address for all the node configuration.